# SyntaxError when installing pip inside Jenkins Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am training over Jenkins and created this simple jenkins image with added features:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

# Install ansible
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py

RUN pip install -U ansible

# Install Docker

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     gnupg2 \
     software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install docker-ce


RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

This worked fine up until a few days ago when my Jenkins went down and now when I try to run this Dockerfile, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmp0ZnKQ5/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The build fails over the first RUN command. I checked that I don't have any typos and that pip didn't change the installation link. If it matters, I am running this on a VM and I am logged through vscode ssh.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax:

```py
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
```

First appeared in python 3.6 if I remember well. It seems your code now uses an older version. There are many things that can go wrong in your Dockerfile, to save your time open a shell in the image and try executing commands manually:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint="" jenkins/jenkins bash
```

Comment: `jenkins/jenkins` image comes with python 2.7.13 so Installing python 3 is the right way?

Comment: @Killerz0ne It will probably fix this problem but can also bring other issues. My guess is that 'install pip' script has been updated. Try changing first `RUN` to `apt update && apt install -y --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends python-pip`.